# In Android, When "include layout" is visible over radio button click, remaining views alignment has changed

Tags: android

[click here to see image When include layout is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbcbj.png)

[click here to see image When include layout is invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWwNA.png)

Images are uploaded
Here is the main.xml

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_prints_type"
        android:text="@string/prints_type"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_prints_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_prints_type_real"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/real"
            android:onClick="showSpoofOptions"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_prints_type_spoof"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/spoof"
            android:onClick="showSpoofOptions"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAsp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <include 
                layout="@layout/asp"
                android:id="@+id/asp_layout"
                android:visibility="gone" />
         </LinearLayout> 
         </TableRow>
         <!--  User Name   -->
         <TableRow
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@drawable/table_row_border">
             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/user"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:textColor="#003366"
                 android:layout_span="2"/>
         </TableRow>
```

and my activity class

```
LinearLayout aspLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutAsp);
aspLayout.removeAllViews();
View aspView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.asp, aspLayout, true);
```

When include Layout is in invisible "Alignment has properly set
When include layout is visible over radio button click Alignment has changed and remaining view components has moved to right corner of the border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android:layout_span="2"

I found the solution for this issue is adding the above simple line to the LinearLayout

Now the Linear Layout be like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAsp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_span="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include 
        layout="@layout/asp"
        android:id="@+id/asp_layout"
        android:visibility="gone" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this will fix things but you need to specify the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of your `<include .../>`. Weird stuff can sometimes happen when you don't.
As an example:
This:

```
<include 
    layout="@layout/asp"
    android:id="@+id/asp_layout"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Should be something along the lines of:

```
<include 
    layout_width="match_parent"
    layout_width="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/asp"
    android:id="@+id/asp_layout"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Yes, I know it seems a little silly that you need to respecify these attributes whenever you use the include tag. Hopefully that fixes things. :)

**Edit**
Have you tried:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAsp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

i.e. Change `layout_width="wrap_content"` to `layout_width="match_parent"`. Try not to use `fill_parent`? `fill_parent` has been deprecated for a while now.

Comment: It's still same like before. Even after adding these elements :'(

Comment: Darn, it was worth a shot xD

Answer (score 0):

you need TableLayout and give height and width to include layout

```
 <TableLayout
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           //your other layouts
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         //your other layouts
   </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>
```

and change this also
layout_height = "fill_parent"

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAsp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include 
            layout="@layout/asp"
            android:id="@+id/asp_layout"
            android:visibility="gone" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

to
layout_height = "wrap_content"

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAsp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include 
            layout="@layout/asp"
            android:id="@+id/asp_layout"
            android:visibility="gone" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried all combinations with LinearLayout and include..
Still having same problem.